# Trouble with json parsing in spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm setting a streaming with spark where data will be read from a S3 bucket and a streaming to a application will be defined. However, the query returns an error while reading the json within the data's columns.

For example, if I start the streaming as

```
val stream = spark.readStream.format("delta").load("my_path").where("apply condition")
```

And then apply a `withWatermark` and a group by, i get the error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.actions.CommitInfo: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Basically, within the `where` i'm restricting data to be no older than a treshold to reduce its size (if i don't do that, i have a memory error).

Comment: Please give more detail about code and exception

Comment: What's the versions of Spark and the delta data source? How do you execute the app?